# How to set dynamic label for filter in flask-admin

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-admin

I have a requirement where i need to allow my site admin to set label for my columns for my Listing page. I have used following code to fetch labels form database and set it for columns.

```
def get_field():
    db=getConnection()
    field_cur = db.cursor()
    getField = "select column_name, name, validation from slb_opp_fields"
    field_cur.execute(getField)
    ValField = {}
    for k in field_cur.fetchall():
        if k[2] == 'Y':
            ValField[k[0]] = k[1]
        else:
            ValField[k[0]] = k[1]
    return ValField


@property
def column_labels(self):
    ValueField, ValField =get_field()
    column_lables = {
        'etb_id': ValField['etb_id'],
        'network_id': ValField['network_id'],
        'domain_area': ValField['domain_area'],
        'service_offering': ValField['service_offering'],
        'customer_unit': 'Customer Unit'
    }

@property
def column_filters(self):
    ValueField, ValField =get_field()
    column_lables = {
        'etb_id': ValField['etb_id'],
        'network_id': ValField['network_id'],
        'domain_area': ValField['domain_area'],
        'service_offering': ValField['service_offering'],
        'customer_unit': 'Customer Unit'
    }

@property
def _list_columns(self):
    return self.get_list_columns()

@_list_columns.setter
def _list_columns(self, value):
    pass

@property
def _filters(self):
    return self.get_filters()

@_filters.setter
def _filters(self, value):
    pass

Where get_field() function fetches data for label(name) from database table as follows:

def get_field():
    db=getConnection()
    field_cur = db.cursor()
    getField = "select column_name, name, validation from slb_opp_fields"
    field_cur.execute(getField)
    ValField = {}
    for k in field_cur.fetchall():
        if k[2] == 'Y':
            ValField[k[0]] = k[1]
        else:
            ValField[k[0]] = k[1]
    return ValField
```

This code works fine for labels in the column in tables list dynamically, but the filter does not reflect label name changes dynamically.

I have used setters for both as per "flask-admin/flask_admin/model/base.py" but still it does not reflect changes for Add Filter section labels.

Python Version 2.7.6
Flask Version: 0.10